# How to Delete Old Comments by Date?

Tags: comments, mysql, date-time

I run a contest/giveaway blog at www.mommylivingthelifeofriley.com and currently have over 160,000 comments on 1100 posts.  I would like to find a way to delete all comments from my site which are older than 6 months, so as to improve my site's overall performance.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

You could easily do this using mysql:

```
DELETE FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_date < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH)
```

Comment: just keep in mind that you may orphan some newer child comments by deleting their older parents.

Comment: I might have time to create simple plugin for this. But, I have questions: what's the best solution for old comments that has new childs? should the old comment be deleted along with it's childs? or should it be preserved? or maybe something better (that I don't know yet)?